# For loop extracts incomplete title from file set

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I tried using a batch script to automate bulk renaming files by extracting title value from mkvinfo.

Now, I have some files with titles like:

```
"Downloaded From: WWW.BEPRITY.COM - FACE.MASK.S23"
```

As a result my files are renamed to:

```
"Downloaded From.mkv"
```

I'm suspecting an issue with the colon in the name.

Here's my batch script

```bash
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%F in (*.mkv) do (
    set "title="
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ('mkvinfo "%%F" ^| find "Title"') do (
        set "title=%%A"
        set "title=!title:~1!"
    )
    if defined title (
        ren "%%F" "!title!.mkv"
        echo Renamed "%%F" to "!title!.mkv"
    ) else (
        echo No title found for "%%F"
    )
)

endlocal
```

Comment: Change `tokens=2` to `tokens=1,*`, then you can rename using `%%B` instead; e.g. ```set "title=%%B"```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided us with the format that `mkvinfo` reports on the selected line.

I suspect that that line is

```
Title: Downloaded From: WWW.BEPRITY.COM - FACE.MASK.S23
```

which would generate that problem, whereas

```
Title: FACE.MASK.S23
```

would be processed correctly.

I'd suggest the `for %%A` should be

```
for /f "tokens=2,* delims=:" %%A in ('mkvinfo "%%F" ^| find "Title"') do (
    set "title=%%B"
    if not defined title set "title=%%A"
    set "title=!title:~1!"
)
```

which should set `%%A` to  `Downloaded From` and `%%B` to  `WWW.BEPRITY.COM - FACE.MASK.S23` for `Downloaded From: WWW.BEPRITY.COM - FACE.MASK.S23`

and

`%%A` to  `FACE.MASK.S23` and `%%B` to *nothing* for  `FACE.MASK.S23`